# Alert Switch Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?

I'm trying to create an alert switcher for my label but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.
If I add this to my JS file, my add button won't work anymore
Can anyone help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.hide', function () {
        console.log('hide');
        $('form').hide();
    });

    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button.add', function () {
        console.log('add');
        var edit = $('#edit');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

        edit.show();
        if (!($('#addNew').length)) {
            edit.append('<input type="button" id="addNew" onclick="addNewTr()" value="Add" name="submit" />');
        }

        if (editRow) {
            editRow.remove();
        }

        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    });

    $('#show').click(function () {
        //$('form').show();
        //$('#btd1').val('Vlad');
        //$('#btd2').val('Andrei');
        //$('#btd3').val('vTask');
        //  $('#btd4').val('Ceva');
        //$('#btd5').val('Alceva');
    });
});

function edit(a) {
    var edit = $('#edit');
        addNew = $('#addNew');
        editRow = $('#editRow');

    edit.show();
    if (addNew) {
        addNew.remove();
    }

    if (editRow.length) {
        editRow.replaceWith('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    } else  {
        edit.append('<input type="button" id="editRow" onclick="save(' + a + ')" value="Edit" name="submit" />');
    }

    $.each($('.tr-' + a).find('td'), function (key, val) {
        $('form#edit input[type=text]').eq(key).val($(val).text());
    });
}

function save(a) {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input, select').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please complete all the colums' + inputName + '\n';
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        for (var q = 1; q < $('.tr-' + a + ' td').length; q++) {
            $('.tr-' + a + ' td:nth-child(' + q + ')').html($('#btd' + q).val());
        }
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
        $('#editRow').remove();
    }
}

function addNewTr() {
    var tr = $('tr');
    valid = true;
    message = '';

    $('form#edit input, select').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.val()) {
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            /*switch (inputName) {
    case 'Nume Proiect':
          message += 'Message for password ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Task Select':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Volum':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Unitati':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Ore Lucrate':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;

    }*/
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        alert(message);
    } else {
        $('table tbody').append('' +
            '<tr class="tr-' + tr.length + '">' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd1').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd2').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd3').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd4').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd5').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#btd6').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td class="buttons">' +
            '<button class="removeThis" onclick="removeThis(' + tr.length + ')">Delete</button >' +
            '<button class="edit" onclick="edit(' + tr.length + ')">Edit</button >' +
            '</td >' +
            '</tr>' +
            '');
        for (var x = 1; x < $('input').length; x++) {
            $('#btd' + x).val('');
        }
    }
}

function removeThis(a) {
    $('.tr-' + a).remove();
}
```

```css
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #e80041;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #188f84;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Top Header */

#hh1 {
color: #1b998b;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
border-bottom: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
font-family: Sans-serif;
height: 200px;
   width: 1300px;
position: fixed;
   top: 20%;
   left: 26.5%;
   margin-top: -100px;
   margin-left: -200px;

}

#vt1 {
color: White;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
position: fixed;
   top: 35%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -100px;
   margin-left: -200px;

}

/* BODY */

body {
  font-family: serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

table.greenTable {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  border: 6px solid #152842;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}
table.greenTable td, table.greenTable th {
  border: 4px solid #1F6698;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.greenTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
table.greenTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #999DA5;
}
table.greenTable thead {
  background: #93B5C1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aec7d0 0%, #9dbcc7 66%, #93B5C1 100%);
  border-bottom: 0px solid #444444;
}
table.greenTable thead th {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #1B998B;
}
table.greenTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.greenTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.greenTable tfoot .links {
  text-align: right;
}
table.greenTable tfoot .links a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* BUTTONS */

/* BODY */

button {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
}
button:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
}

#addNew {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
}
#addNew:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
}

#editRow {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #152842;
  background: #63B8EE;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1F6698), to(#1B998B));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1F6698,  #1B998B);
}
#editRow:hover {
  color: #14396A !important;
  background: #468CCF;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#93B5C1), to(#D1D1D1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #93B5C1,  #D1D1D1);
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.read-more {
    background: #222;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 6px #eee;
}
.read-more:before {
    content: "<<";
    color: #fff;
}
#content {
 color: #222;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 30%;
 margin: 200px auto 0;
 padding: 50px;
 border: 4px solid #222;
}
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #222222;
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
}
#status {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
    padding: 0;
}


textarea {
  width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/pontare.css">
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
  <table class="greenTable" id="myTable" width="80%">
    <tbody>

  <tr><td colspan="7"><form id="edit" action="" method="post" hidden >

<label for="btd1" ></label >
   <input type="text" name="Nume Proiect" id="btd1" value="" placeholder="Nume Proiect *">

  <label for="btd2" ></label >
<select type="text" name="Task Select" id="btd2" required>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Task Select *</option>
<option value="Librarie">Librarie</option>
<option value="Delete">Delete</option>
<option value="Marcaj">Marcaj</option>
<option value="Mancare">Mancare</option>
<option value="Suc">Suc</option>
</select>

<label for="btd3" ></label >
<input type="number" name="Volum" id="btd3" value="" placeholder="Volum *">

  <label for="btd4" ></label >
<select type="text" name="Unitati" id="btd4" required>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Unitati *</option>
<option value="ore">Ore</option>
<option value="caractere">Caractere</option>
<option value="imagini">Imagini</option>
<option value="tabele">Tabele</option>
<option value="fisiere">Fisiere</option>
</select>

  <label for="btd5" ></label >
      <input type="number" name="Ore Lucrate" id="btd5" value="" placeholder="Ore Lucrate *">

<label for="btd6" ></label >
<textarea id="btd6" name="comments" id="comments" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;" placeholder="Comment">
</textarea>
</form >
</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">Nume Proiect</td>
<td width="10%">Task Select</td>
  <td width="10%">Volum</td>
  <td width="10%">Unitati</td>
  <td width="10%">Ore Lucrate</td>
  <td class="buttons" width="10%" colspan="2"><button class="add" >Add</button >
  <button class="hide" >Hide</button >
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table >
</body>
</html>
```

I edited my Codes so I can give you guys a full see of my html/js/css

So where the switch is disable try delete the message and activate the switch. After you do that the Add button will not work anymore
Thats my problem with the switch

Comment: You are also missing curly braces on for your if-statement and to close out your function

Comment: Tried that also. nothing worked :(

Comment: That wasn't the answer but just another thing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use strin propely quoted  in case

```
switch (inputName) {
    case 'Nume Proiect':
          message += 'Message for password ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Task Select':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Volum':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Unitati':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;
    case 'Ore Lucrate':
          message += 'Message for email ' + inputName + '\n';
          break;

    }
```

and  capital case too  as suggested by Matt

Comment: explain better  ... you have error?   ... check in the browser console for error and let me know

Comment: capital letters for switch and case?

Comment: can you tell me please in the case what should I put? ID or what should I add in that?

Comment: you are switching on input name and so you shoudl put the valid (string) value for your attr('name')   alias the name of your elem

Comment: I don't have no value on my labels

Comment: This is a example of my Input/Lable HTML Code

Comment: <label for="btd3" ></label >
<input type="number" name="Volum" id="btd3" value="" placeholder="Volum *">

Comment: then you should have a value for name ='Volum' and a case 'Volum': ... check what you really have in inputName using alert(inputName);

Comment: what  mean  "its not working"  .. you have error?    ... show the error message ..  check in your browser  console for see the error ..

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at onload (pontare.html:6)

Comment: the error you get by javascript is related  to a part of code  you have not  in your actua question  .. so i suggest you of post a new question related  to the part of code mentioned in your javascript message error ... (the part of code you have in this question can't be evalueated by javascript if an error is encountered  before reaching this code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155963/discussion-between-andrei-ref-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Edited my Code up. Now you can see it fully

Comment: Your code don't contain a function named "myFunction"   .. could be you are calling  myFunction in your html ... but not exist in your script  ..